# Spresense SDK環境でのキャラクターLCD表示

Tags: spresense

Spresense SDK 環境でI2C接続をしたキャラクターLCDに文字を表示をさせようとしていますが、プログラミングの資料や前例が見つかりません。ソースコードそのものの例がなくとも、せめて何を呼び出せばよいかが分かればよいのですが、どなたかご存知でしょうか？

10月29日追記
arduinoでのLCD表示例はすでに見つけているのですが、arduinoとSupresense SDKとの変換で詰まってしまっています(SDKのライブラリを探して右往左往している段階)。同じく秋月電子で購入した温度センサーLMT01LPGを使用して温度を測定しようとしたのですが、arduinoだとGPIO入力でのチャタリングフィルタの解除方法が分からず動作するものができなかったのでSDKでプログラムしています(SDKでの温度取得はすでに成功しています)。この手のマイコンボードのプログラミング自体初めてでarduino自体正直よくわかっていません。申し訳ありません。

10月30日追記
SDK環境の場合I2Cポートの選択や設定はソースコード上ではなく「カーネルコンフィグ」、「SDKコンフィグ」でソースファイルとは別に行うという事とI2C接続でのキャラクターLCDドライバーとして「pcf8574_lcd_backpack.h」が用意されていることがわかりました。また、「pcf8574_lcd_backpack.txt」にある程度使い方が書いてありました。しかし、細かい使い方がまだ理解できていません。使ったことのある方アドバイス願えますでしょうか？

11月10日追記
LCDドライバー「pcf8574_lcd_backpack.h」を使用しようとするとカーネルパニックが発生し動作が停止します。原因を調べていくうちにデバイスパス(例「/dev/lcd0」)が生成できていないことが判明しました。どうもlcdデバイスを初期化する必要があるようですが、必要なコマンドがわかりません。どなたかご存知でしょうか？今の段階では
int board_i2cdev_initialize(void);
FAR struct lcd_dev_s *board_lcd_getdev(int lcddev);
を使用すればよいのか？という認識ですが実際の使い方が理解できていません。

Comment: 一般的な話であれば「i2c lcd arduino」で検索するだけで実例がいくつか出てくるかと思います。 / LCDモジュールの型番等、詳しい情報も載せておくと、回答も付きやすくなるでしょう。

Comment: 今回使おうとしているLCDモジュールの型番はXiamen Zettler Electronics Co., Ltd. ACM0802C-NLW-BBW-IIC。秋月電子で扱っている8×2 I2Cキャラクタディスプレイです。

Comment: 操作ミスで送信してしまいました。続き　-->　arduinoでのLCD表示例はすでに見つけているのですが、arduinoとSupresense SDKとの変換で詰まってしまっています(SDKのライブラリを探して右往左往している段階)。同じく秋月電子で購入した温度センサーLMT01LPGを使用して温度を測定しようとしたのですが、arduinoだとGPIO入力でのチャタリングフィルタの解除方法が分からず動作できるものができなかったのでSDKでプログラムしています(SDKでの温度取得はすでに成功しています)。この手のマイコンボードのプログラミング自体初めてでarduino自体正直よくわかっていません。申し訳ありません。

Comment: 現時点で、SDK環境の場合I2Cポートの選択や設定は「カーネルコンフィグ」、「SDKコンフィグ」でソースファイルとは別に行うという事とI2C接続でのキャラクターLCDドライバーとして「pcd8544.h」が用意されていることがわかりました。

Comment: 質問に関わる情報については、質問本文を直接 [編集] で追記してみてください。意味のある編集を行うことで質問一覧の上位に上がるので、みんなの目に止まりやすくなります。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。やってみます

Answer (score 1):

私も秋月のACM0802C-NLW-BBW-IICを持っていたので、
SpresenseでLCD表示をどうすれば良いか、調べてみました。

「pcf8574_lcd_backpack.h」は、該当のドライバでは無いようですね。。

自分で作ってみたものがあるので、
githubにアップしてみました。

https://github.com/tttk-prj/spresense.git

このリポジトりの中の、
examples/lcd_test
というフォルダにLCDのドライバとそれを使ったコードを入れてあります。

ビルドの仕方は、このリポジトリをクローンしたら、

```
 $ cd spresense/sdk/
 $ ./tools/config.py -k release
 $ make buildkernel
 $ ./tools/config.py -d ../examples/lcd_test lcd_test
 $ make
 $ ./tools/flash.sh -c /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 1152000 nuttx.spk
```

として、nuttx.spkをデバイスに書き込みます。
（ポイントは、configで"-d"オプションを使って、examples/lcd_testの中に入れてある、lcd_test-defconfigを指定しているところ）

そのあと、ターミナルソフトでspresenseのメインボードのUSBポートと繋いで、

```
nsh> lcd_test
```

でLCDが表示されます。（のはず。。）

HWの接続は、

ACM0802C-NLW-BBW-IIC側の10ピンのピン番号をACM_01 〜 ACM_10として、
Spresense側は、https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/introduction_ja.html に記載されているピン名とすると、

```
ACM_01(Vss)  <->  GND
ACM_02(Vdd)  <->  VOUT
ACM_03(V0 )  <->  GND
ACM_04(SA1)  <->  D09(PWM2)
ACM_05(SA0)  <->  D08(SPI2_MISO)
ACM_06(SDA)  <->  D14(I2C0_BDT)
ACM_07(SCL)  <->  D15(I2C0_BCK)
ACM_08(NC )  <->  NC
ACM_09(BL+)  <->  EXT_VDD(Mainボード)
ACM_10(BL-)  <->  GND
```

です。
SA0とSA1は、D０８、D０９に接続して、プログラム上でLOWにして、デバイスアドレスを0x78にしてます。

ところで、
SpresenseとこのLCDディスプレイは相性が悪いようですね。。

[https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/hw_docs_ja.html#_拡張基板でのデジタル信号uartspipwmgpio使用上の注意](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/hw_docs_ja.html#_%E6%8B%A1%E5%BC%B5%E5%9F%BA%E6%9D%BF%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E3%83%87%E3%82%B8%E3%82%BF%E3%83%AB%E4%BF%A1%E5%8F%B7uartspipwmgpio%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%AE%E6%B3%A8%E6%84%8F)

この注意点に記載されてる現象にハマリリました。。。

I2CのACKフェーズでACK（LOW)を認識してくれないようです。。
解決するには、外付けにバッファを付けるような指示が書いてありましたが、
持っていないのと仮に持っていても面倒だったので、
リポジトリに上げたコードでは、ソフトウェアでI2Cをエミュレートして、
かつ、ACKフェーズは無視して、コマンドを強引に送ることで表示できるようにしました。。。

一応、ハードウェアのI2Cマスタも使えるよう、コードは入れています。
ハードウェアを有効にするには、一旦ビルドした後に、
spresense/sdkフォルダで、

```
 $ make menuconfig
```

で、
Examples -> Test driver of ACM0802C-NLW-BBW-IIC
の中の、
「Use Spresense HW IIC peripheral」
を有効にすれば、出来るはず、です。。

以上、参考になれば良いですが。。。

Answer (score 0):

[SpresenseでLチカから始める (4) Wireライブラリ キャラクタLCD](https://www.denshi.club/cookbook/arduino/spresense/spresensel-4-wire-i2clcd.html) の記事が参考になるのでは？

時間に余裕がある時に、"SpresenseでLチカから始める"の連載記事を(1)から順に読んでいくと、いろいろな知識が身についてSpresenseでのプログラミングスキルを上げられると思いますよ。

Comment: ここはすでに読みました。Arduino環境でとりあえず動かす段(Lチカ)で実際にこの連載でも勉強させていただきました。ここを参照にLCDを駆動しようとしてSDKだとwire(及び該当する)ライブラリがないことに気が付きました。